# How can I get my asp:TreeView control to recognize the TreeNodeCheckChanged method I wrote?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, treeview

I'm having a really frustrating issue with a TreeView control in a Web Form. I'm using C# on Visual Studio, and, admittedly, this is my first project on the platform, so there are a lot of caveats I'm finding I'm not aware of.

The page I'm working on isn't that complicated. In the body of WebPage.aspx, I have an empty TreeView control declared, along with a Label to display output (for testing) and a Button to cause a postback:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="SimpleTreeView" runat="server">
</asp:TreeView>
<asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server">No change yet.</asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" PostBackUrl="~/WebPage.aspx" />
```

I populate the TreeView programmatically within the Page_Load method of my WebPage class, based on data in our SQL server. That part works like a charm.

Now, I want to define the event handler for the TreeView's TreeNodeCheckChanged event. Firstly, YES, I know that the event does not fire immediately when a checkbox is changed; 99% of everything I can find on the Internet about this is people complaining about that. For my application, waiting until the button is clicked is fine.

I've followed what [the MSDN article on the event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodecheckchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does, by adding the OnTreeNodeCheckChanged attribute to the TreeView control:

```
<asp:TreeView ... OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="CheckChangedMethod">
```

and added a corresponding method to the WebPage class in WebPage.aspx.cs:

```
protected void CheckChangedMethod( object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e )
{
    StatusLabel.Text = "A checkbox was changed!";
}
```

When I launch the page, though, I get an error screen that says:

**CS1061: 'ASP.webpage_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'CheckChangedMethod' and no extension method 'CheckChangedMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webpage_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I have found that if I move the method to within a  tag on WebPage.aspx, it works! Unfortunately, though, I need the method to access classes and methods in other parts of the site, which I can't from within the script tag (...right?). How can I get my event handler recognized by the compiler without removing it from the WebPage class?

**Edit:**

The total markup looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Web Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireUp="true" CodeBehind="WebPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.WebPage" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolKit" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolder="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <!-- This is where I placed the script tag to test the method -->
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolder="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <h2><em>Headline</em></h2>
    <br />
    <asp:TreeView ID="SimpleTreeView" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0" ShowCheckBoxes="All">
    </asp:TreeView>
    <asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server">No change yet.</asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" PostBackUrl="~/WebPage.aspx" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: can you show the .aspx page's Markup from the very first line where it either says CodeFile= or CodeBehind=

Comment: Sure... Give me a sec. I had to change file names because the project is for work.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Not sure what happened, but after fixing bugs elsewhere on our site, the code above magically decided to start working. I'm not going to question it.